# Installing OpenShift as Docker image behind nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, openshift-origin

I'm playing around with docker and I'm facing right now an issue that I could not solve.

I've installed Jenkins, SonarQube, Nexus, Postgres, openshift as Docker images and set them up behind nginx as a reverse proxy, which itself is installed as a docker image.

Routing is all working fine but for openshift. I create and run the container as per the documentation but changing the network to "bridge" so nginx and openshift are in the same network.

```
$ sudo docker run -d --name "origin" \
    --privileged --pid=host --net=bridge \
    -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw -v /sys:/sys -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw \
    -v /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes \
    openshift/origin start
```

Listing the containers I get

```
root@v22015111607829502:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                    NAMES
c1e3fe0d7fb6        nginx-img            "nginx"                  22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes           0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       nginx
208fd0f387e0        openshift/origin     "/usr/bin/openshift s"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour        53/tcp, 8443/tcp         openshift
2a1a2d2cfa6a        sonar-img            "./bin/run.sh"           2 days ago          Up About an hour        9000/tcp                 sonar
baf34805dcac        postgres-img         "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 days ago          Up About an hour        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgres
302b53c74bd5        nexus-img            "/bin/sh -c '${JAVA_H"   2 days ago          Up About an hour        8081/tcp                 nexus
31e6560c6584        jenkins-master-img   "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   2 days ago          Up About an hour        8080/tcp, 50000/tcp      jenkins-master
a886b94db083        jenkins-data-img     "echo 'Data container"   3 days ago          Exited (0) 3 days ago                            jenkins-data
```

Only postgres and nginx can be accessed from outside. I Run nginx linking to the the other containers with

```
docker run -p 80:80 --name=nginx --link jenkins-master:jenkins-master --link nexus:nexus --link sonar:sonar --link openshift:openshift -d nginx-img
```

Anyway, when I try to call openshift through nginx with

```
http://myipaddress/paas
```

The browser try to download a file (application/octec-stream) and on the nginx error.log I get

```
root@v22015111607829502:~# docker exec nginx cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
2016/07/24 10:51:06 [error] 9#0: *1 upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream, client: 78.53.33.101, server: , request: "GET /paas/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.6:8443/", host: "myipaddress"
```

This is the nginx.conf

```
daemon off; 

user nginx; 

worker_processes 10; 

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn; 
pid /var/run/nginx.pid; 

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex off;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    # default_type application/text/html;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;

    #tcp_nopush on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    client_max_body_size 300m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 0;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/javascript application/json;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_vary on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And the sites.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "";
    access_log off;

    location ^~ /ci/ {
        proxy_pass http://jenkins-master:8080/ci/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    location ^~ /nexus/ {
        proxy_pass http://nexus:8081/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    location ^~ /sonar/ {
        proxy_pass http://sonar:9000/sonar/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    location ^~ /paas/ {
        proxy_pass https://openshift:8443/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

}
```

If I run openshift docker container with

```
--net=host
```

and I call openshift with

```
http://myipaddress:8443/
```

I get encrypted data like

```
�
```

But if call openshift on browser with

```
https://myipaddress:8443/
```

than it works. I think the problem could be that

1. It should be a kind of rewrite from http to https if calling http://myipaddress:8443
2. As the browser checks NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when calling https://myipaddress:8443, if using nginx, it gets the browser confirmation page first for accepting the unsecured connection and this is not expected by nginx. Thus I get an 502 error message page.

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this? Is this an acceptable approach?

**UPDATE**

If openshift is running on --net=host and I change the location config for openshift to

```
    location ^~ /paas/ {
        proxy_pass https://$host:8443/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

It "almost" work but the browser shows the port. How can I get nginx to not redirect the request?